# Bean properties not null during initialization become null during @Transactional method invocation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I am encountering an issue where a bean's properties become null during invocation of a `@Transactional` method.

- `UserService` is a bean declared in a `@Configuration` class
- `userRepository` and `passwordService` are non null during initialization `(afterPropertiesSet)`
- during invocation of registerUser (which is `@Transactional`), these properties become null
- these properties have non nullable types
- same instance/bean of UserService has been used based on prints
- removing `@Transactional` seems to fix the issue
- adding or removing `@EnableTransactionManagement` seems to do nothing

Service:

```
open class UserService (val userRepository: UserRepository,
                        val passwordService: PasswordService) : InitializingBean {

    override fun afterPropertiesSet() {
        println("### this.afterPropertiesSet")
        println("### this: " + this)
        println("### userRepository: " + userRepository)
        println("### passwordService: " + passwordService)
    }

    @Transactional
    fun registerUser(request: UserRegistrationRequest): User {
        println("### this.registerUser")
        println("### this: " + this)
        println("### userRepository: " + userRepository)
        println("### passwordService: " + passwordService)
        val savedUser = this.userRepository.save(request.toUser())
        this.passwordService.savePassword(savedUser, request.password)
        return savedUser
    }

    private fun UserRegistrationRequest.toUser(): User { ... }

}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
class UserController (val userService: UserService) : InitializingBean {
    override fun afterPropertiesSet() {
        println("### controller.afterPropertiesSet: " + userService)
        println("### user service: " + userService)
    }

    @PostMapping("/users")
    fun registerUser(@RequestBody userDetails: UserDetailsDto): ResponseEntity<UserDto> {
        println("### controller.registerUser: " + userService)
        println("### user service: " + userService)
        val registeredUser = userService.registerUser(userDetails.toUserRegistrationRequest())
        return ResponseEntity.ok(registeredUser.toDto())
    }

    private fun UserDetailsDto.toUserRegistrationRequest(): UserRegistrationRequest { ... }

    private fun User.toDto(): UserDto { ... }
}
```

Bean declaration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
open class ApplicationServicesConfiguration {

    @Bean
    open fun userService(userRepository: UserRepository,
                         passwordService: PasswordService): UserService = UserService(userRepository, passwordService)

    @Bean
    open fun passwordService(passwordRepository: PasswordRepository): PasswordService = PasswordService(passwordRepository)

}
```

Prints:

```
### this.afterPropertiesSet
### this: com.sample.mojo.user.UserService@1ab14636
### userRepository: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository@1961d75a
### passwordService: com.sample.mojo.user.PasswordService@36359723

### controller.afterPropertiesSet: com.sample.mojo.user.UserService@1ab14636
### user service: com.sample.mojo.user.UserService@1ab14636

### controller.registerUser: com.sample.mojo.user.UserService@1ab14636
### user service: com.sample.mojo.user.UserService@1ab14636

### this.registerUser
### this: com.sample.mojo.user.UserService@1ab14636
### userRepository: null
### passwordService: null
```

Package structure

```
com.sample.app.Application
com.sample.app.ApplicationServicesConfiguration
com.sample.app.user.UserController
com.sample.app.user.UserService
com.sample.app.user.UserRepository
com.sample.app.user.PasswordService
```

Is this a Spring bug? Or a Kotlin-Spring integration quirk?

Comment: Did you try by annotation `UserService` with `@Service`?

Comment: I didn't. But I declared UserService as a `@Bean` in a `@Configuration` class. Added bean declaration for clarity.

Comment: @BranislavLazic added package structure as requested

Comment: Not that familiar with Kotlin but the `@Transactional fun` seems to be final. Which makes it non-proxyable and hence it will use the instances of the proxy (which are `null`) instead of the calling the actually wrapped instance. Try making the function `open`.

Answer (score 0):

Try marking the transactional function as open.

There is a gradle plugin for marking all classes as open:

```
buildscript{
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:$kotlinVersion")
    }
}
apply plugin: 'kotlin-spring'
```